# Request client certificate by site on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-cloud-services

I deployed my **MVC 4** application on **Azure**, installed own CA, create self-signed certificate and certificate for server (https working good). How can I activate **require client certificates** signed by my CA and working only with it?

[image: I need this on Azure]

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Include solutions that you've tried and detailed explanation why they don't work. And, unless you've thoroughly tested locally and everything is working fine do not put tag Azure. When you tag something with Azure it means it is specific to Azure. But your problem seems to be just programming related with no relation to Azure at all. You will have same question/problem to solve if you host it anywhere else.

Comment: Locally all working fine. I enabled client certificate on IIS and browser ask certificate. But I can't understand, how to enable this request on Azure web site, using Azure website manager.

Comment: your update still doesn't show what have you tried so far, beside a simple `point-and-click` deployment. Plus, be explicit in what service are you using - Azure Web Sites or Azure Cloud Services?

Comment: Azure Web Site. I need to find option on Azure, like on image higher. Locally after I checked checkbox "Require SSL" and choosed "Require" for client certificates in IIS 8, all working as I want. But at manage.windowsazure.com in settings of my website  I found only Server Certificate. Problems with site settings, not with application. I tried to resolve like by this link http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/using-client-certificates, but it's different from my problem. Can I enable require client certificates option on azure or I need create virtual machine with IIS?

Comment: vote for it at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/32367727-classic-cloud-service-ssl-require-client-certific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two viable options you have, you already described in your comments.

One is to use Azure VM and IIS (I don't like it) - there you know what to do.

The other one is to use a Web Role (Cloud Service) and do the things described in the [link you refer to](http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/using-client-certificates). I advise you to take the Web Role path.

Or third option, is to wait until (if ever) Windows Azure Web Sites to unlock the required property in application host config. Check [this SO question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719416/can-client-certificate-settings-be-configured-in-the-web-config) on what you need to do in your web.config in order to achieve your goal. The catch is that `access` section under `system.webServer/security` is locked at application host config level, and can only be unlocked when you have Azure Web Role.

Just fyi, [here is a list of overridable sections in your web.config](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/07/09/Tweaking-Windows-Azure-Web-Sites.aspx) when you use Azure Web Sites.

Comment: I choosed VM with server 2012 and IIS 8, it's easier for me and working perfectly

Comment: yeah, it will. But I highly encourage you to give Web Role a chance! Go and try it! you can easily unlock this section with simple start-up task! And you will have much powerful and easy to manage deployment!