# Require SSL Client Certificate only for specific routes or controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I have an ASP.NET MVC Core project using Kestrel as the server. It is both serving up user content (asp.net mvc) and hosts web API controllers that agents (software) communicate with. I have enabled HTTPS and client certificate support. The issue is that I want to require client certificates for agents (software) that call Web APIs but I do not want to require/prompt for client certificates for regular browser based users.

I have enabled HTTPS/client certificate support the following way:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    HttpsConnectionFilterOptions httpsoptions = new    HttpsConnectionFilterOptions();
    httpsoptions.ServerCertificate = CertUtil.GetServerCert();
    httpsoptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
    httpsoptions.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;

    options.UseHttps(httpsoptions);
})
.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000", "https://0.0.0.0:5001")
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
host.Run();
```

I have a separate middleware handler setup in Startup.cs to handle custom verification of client certificates. This code does successfully execute and everything works fine in that sense.

The problem is this happens globally and I am only looking to apply client certificates to specific controllers and/or routes; or really I would take any granularity at this point.

Essentially trying to create the same sort of behavior you can get in IIS by creating two virtual directories and then setting SSL Settings to Accept on one and Ignore on the other. The one with Accept will prompt the browser for a cert and the one with Ignore will not.

I tried setting HttpsConnectionFilterOptions to only specify ServerCertificate in hopes that not setting any client certificate related options would allow the server to receive client certificates if they are sent but otherwise not prompt browsers for them. This did not seem to work as my middleware client certificate handler never sees a client cert when calling this function (it does when ClientCertificateMode is set to AllowCertificate.

```
context.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();
```

I guess in short does Kestrel hosting even allow for more granular client certificate mapping/handling or is it only possible using IIS? IIS is not an option for this project and I would rather prefer not having to create a separate project/process just for the client cert api aspects. Appreciate any help!

Comment: BTW this question here is similar in nature but doing it for IIS vs. self hosted asp.net core with Kestrel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323880/disable-ssl-client-certificate-on-some-webapi-controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been trying to do the same thing, with exactly the same requirements as you.

I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible. My workaround is to use *2* `WebHostBuilder` objects - one for locations that *don't* need client certs, and one for those that *do*. This does have the downside that each `IWebHost` must listen on a different port, but from the scenario you describe I guess that's not a big issue.

I do this within the same process, so this solution fits that requirement.

Comment: I have also recently found this to really be the only workable solution at the moment. Dev team seemed to recommend the same thing: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1162#issuecomment-253291237 Thank you!

Comment: Wondering if anyone has a new/better way of doing this now that asp.net core 2.0 is out?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with `context.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();` it was always returning null. Then I noticed that I was running Kestrel thru IIS Express all the time.

So in Visual Studio from the Debuger toolbar I changed from IIS Express to my project. Kestrel was started as console application and I was able to get the client certificate.

[image]

I think that IIS Express does not support client certificates so the certificate was always ignored.

For the other part of the question; I think Kestrel dos not support this granularity that you are looking out of the box when using the `HttpsConnectionFilterOptions`. From the [Kestrel Connection Filter Options source code](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https/HttpsConnectionFilter.cs#L68) the connection will be dropped if the client certificate is null. Maybe you can modify the source code for the `HttpsConnectionFilterOptions` and create your own filter from it. Then you can use the `ClientCertificateValidation` property to specify custom certificate validation method that will allow the connection when no client certificate is send.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to have Client Certificate only on some routes but when run in Azure Web App, the client cert is not being passed to the code. It is the same problem when running under IIS Express.

In this example, One controller needs no cert, the other two requires different certs.
https://github.com/xavierjohn/ClientCertificateMiddleware

The certificate does get passed through if it is **not** run under IIS Express.

Comment: That is actually a really good solution that you built. One thing from a security perspective is that you should be verifying also against the certificate thumbprint as otherwise an attacker could spoof Issuer and Subject very easily whereas thumbprint is a hash of the entire certificate etc... Your solution actually works great under Kestrel. I am not sure what the issue might be under IIS Express or Azure Web App but you can probably open a separate stack overflow thread on that.

Comment: This looks to be relevant to your issue with Azure and not getting client certificates. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2016/04/13/azure-web-app-client-certificate-authentication-with-asp-net-core-2/

Comment: Once I figure out how to get this to work in Azure, I will add the option for thumb print. The problem with thumb print is that we need to keep updating it when certificates expire. For a services that has many partners, this could get painful.

Comment: Here is a document on how to enable certs on Azure Web App.
https://msftplayground.com/2016/06/azure-app-service-and-client-certificate-authentication/

Comment: That is true that keeping all thumbprints up to date can be more work. At the very least though you should look at doing certificate chain validation to make sure that the certificate is valid to a CA that you trust and so on. Essentially you want to be really careful with roll your own certificate validation. There are a lot of good best practices on this worth researching.

Comment: I have added a call to Verify() for chain validation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong guys but enabling client certs on azure means it will be required at any route in entire webapp. There is a feature request to change this behaviour here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/13481457-support-optional-client-certificates-for-tls-mutua

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use isolated (new one) IWebHost to control access to dedicated MVC controllers.
Just use [Athorization Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?#authorization-filters) for this purpose.