# Azure API Management Service doesn't pass the client certificate in the header to the backend

Tags: azure, http, https, azure-api-management

I am facing an issue where I am not able to see the client certificate being passed to the backend when using client certificate authentication using Azure API Management Service.

I have created a https backend where I validate the certificate and put logging to see the headers and the values that come through.

In my API management gateway, I have following policies applied in the "All Operations" of my api

```html
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base/>
        <authentication-certificate thumbprint="AB4495609DEEE612E9DF25CBC9EB4D7064D6EA97"/>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request/>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base/>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base/>
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

In the API call I have the following policy definition

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base/>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base/>
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base/>
</outbound>
```

Now when I make a call to the API, I can see from my backend that I get the following message

8/12/2017 6:24:57 AMOcp-Apim-Subscription-Key:dbxxxx991a3b4b8aa19a4fxxxxxxx
8/12/2017 6:24:57 AMX-ARR-ClientCert header is missing

If I add that header as a policy in the API gateway and set the base 64 encoded value of the cert, it works fine. I would want to use the certificate configured rather than setting the cert in the header if I can avoid it.

I have tried setting backend to http as well as https. Both seem to give the same results.

Just some extra information, my backend is an aspnet core web api project running in a docker container (hosted in an azure ubuntu machine). I have tried hitting the URL directly without the API management gateway by passing in the client certificate in the header and that also works without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-ARR-ClientCert` header is created when [Microsoft ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) is used to do SSL offloading.  When API Management (APIM) uses a client certificate to authenticate against a backend server, it will provide the client certificate at the TLS layer to do this.  This means the call to the backend needs to be using HTTPS. APIM doesn't send the ARR header as that would provide no security at all.  Anyone could fake that header.

I'm not sure your backend is complaining about not getting the ARR Header when a certificate is provided directly.  Usually one or the other should be sufficient for the ASP.NET Web API security pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Darrel, makes sense now.  I have been trying to read the certificate from the backend without much luck. Maybe I need to keep on digging to see how to verify this cert in ASPNET Core. All the samples I have worked with only seem to verify the cert from the web layer

Comment: @Srini  It looks like your ASP.NET Core app is doing something like this https://github.com/kaevans/ClientCertDemo/blob/master/src/ClientCertWeb/ClientCertificateMiddleware.cs which is dependent on being hosted in IIS with ARR enabled.  And I'm not sure if Kestrel has an equivalent feature.

Comment: @Srini  Looks like it is possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665934/asp-net-core-kestrel-server-ssl-client-certificate-only-for-specific-routes-or-c

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion yesterday. Your comment helped me get there with better understanding. The aspnet core kestrel engine is limited and should not be used to face public internet according to Microsoft guides, as it lacks features. Kestrel 2.0 may have the features to support tls security. Haven't tried yet but will give that a go at some point. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore1x

Comment: @Srini  Putting APIM in front of Kestrel is a viable way of exposing a Kestrel hosted API on the web.  All you need to do is ensure that the Kestrel server is only accessible via APIM.  You could do that with IP filtering.