# Specify ClientCertEnabled for a virtual application

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

For an Azure Web App, the only setting available for client certificates is "**ClientCertEnabled**". The problem is that it requires the certificate for the whole site. I can't find another way. I thought about creating a virtual App under the site, is it possible to enable this setting for a virtual App inside Azure? Any config in the ARM Template?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I followed this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth) about enable client certificate authentication when the request is over **TLS/SSL** for your Azure Web App.

**Note:**

> **If you access your site over HTTP and not HTTPS, you will not receive any client certificate**. So if your application requires client certificates you should not allow requests to your application over HTTP.
>
> **The client certificate that is sent to the application does not go through any validatio**n by the Azure Web Apps platform. **Validating this certificate is the responsibility of the web app**.

> The problem is that it requires the certificate for the whole site. I can't find another way. I thought about creating a virtual App under the site, is it possible to enable this setting for a virtual App inside Azure?

I followed this official [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) for deploying a virtual directory to a single Azure Website to test this scenario, and found it did not work at all.

I also followed this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719416/can-client-certificate-settings-be-configured-in-the-web-config) to configure SSL Settings in my config file and followed this official [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/remote-administration-of-windows-azure-websites-using-iis-manager/) for remoting to my Azure Website via IIS Manager to change some settings, in order to achieve this purpose instead of using `ClientCertEnabled`. But all the above trials could not work at all, I assumed that you need to create a new web app which is used to handle requests based on client certificate authentication.

Additionally, here are some useful tutorials you could refer to them:

[Web API with client certificate](http://www.razibinrais.com/secure-web-api-with-client-certificate/)

[Code sample AzureWebApiClientCertAuthSample](https://github.com/rbinrais/AzureWebApiClientCertAuthSample)

[Azure App Service and Client Certificate Authentication](https://msftplayground.com/2016/06/azure-app-service-and-client-certificate-authentication/)

Comment: yes I tried all of those. I will try to enter a feature request for Web Apps.

Comment: You add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps), also you could attach your feedback link here, I would vote for it.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/13481457-support-optional-client-certificates-for-tls-mutua