# Selecta certificate to authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

[image]

I hosted the Asp.net core application on the Azure app service. From time to time I see this message when browsing can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your client side don't have the certificate. So when you open the site, you will see this notification.

**Method 1**

You can change to `Client certificate mode` to allow or ignore.

**Method 2**

You also use `<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />` in your `web.config` file. If you don't have `web.config` file, you can create a new one.

**Related Post:**  [Can Client certificate settings be configured in the web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8721650/7687666)